# Error while installing Juju

Tags: juju

I'm following [this](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/getting-started) article to install Juju.

When I run:

```
sudo lxd init
```

I get an error:

```
error: Unable to talk to LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: connection refused
```

How to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you try installing a [newer version](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/tree/stable-2.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions are probably incorrect to the socket:

```
$ sudo chown root:lxd /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
$ lxc list
```